# psycopg2 string composition error

Tags: psycopg2, psql

I am doing an upsert.

```
owner.sq_properties = ['name', 'place', 'email_address',                      'preferred_transport', 'note', 'address_line_one',                      'address_line_two', 'address_line_three', 'contact_one',                'contact_two', 'contact_three', 'gst_number', 'nickname']
```

statement:

```
sq = sql.SQL("insert into master.customer select * from public.customer on conflict (id) do update set({})=({})").format(sql.SQL(',').join(sql.Identifier(n) for n in owner.sq_properties),sql.SQL(',').join(sql.Identifier("excluded."+n) for n in owner.sq_properties))
```

when I execute:

```
print(sq.as_string(cursor))
```

output is :

```
insert into master.customer select * from public.customer on conflict (id) do update set ("name", "place", "email_address", "preferred_transport", "note", "address_line_one", "address_line_two", "address_line_three", "contact_one", "contact_two", "contact_three", "gst_number", "nickname") = ("excluded.name", "excluded.place", "excluded.email_address", "excluded.preferred_transport", "excluded.note", "excluded.address_line_one", "excluded.address_line_two", "excluded.address_line_three", "excluded.contact_one", "excluded.contact_two", "excluded.contact_three", "excluded.gst_number", "excluded.nickname")
```

error:

```
cursor.execute(sq)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "excluded.name" does not exist
LINE 1: ...o", "contact_three", "gst_number", "nickname") = ("excluded..
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. `excluded.` should be an sql identifier.

```
joined =sql.SQL(',').join(sql.SQL('excluded.')+sql.Identifier(n) for n in owner.sq_properties)
```

corrected statement:

```
sql.SQL("insert into master.customer select * from public.customer on conflict (id) do update set ({}) = ({})      returning id").format(sql.SQL(',').join(sql.Identifier(n) for n in owner.sq_properties), joined)
```